# how to make preprocessing of data in android faster?

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

In my android application which has preprocessing step at the start of the application which loads data needed by the app from database. The size of SQLite database is some 40 MB. The application takes a lot of time to preprocess the data from the database so an user has to wait for some 1 minute time for using the application. Is there any way/ways by which I can improve the performance of my app? The DB operations are mostly of select type like this:

`Cursor mCursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(TimeTaken) as _time from AssessmentAttempted where AssesmentId IN(" + assessmentIds  + ")", null);`

Comment: Can you figure out exactly what takes time ? The DB requests themselves or some java processing ? How many DB requests are there ? Which are the longest ?

Comment: @fiddler I'm sure it is the DB requests which are taking time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To improve the performance on the preprocess phase create a SQL transaction for all operations made against the DB. This will decrease especially the insert and update times.

```
myDataBase.beginTransaction();
try {
    //make all the BD operations
    myDataBase.setTransactionSuccessful();
}catch {
    //Error in between database transaction 
}finally {
    myDataBase.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is db here?

Comment: I update the answer, is your SQLite DB, in your code `myDataBase` object.